# Quickly add + to positive strings [PHP]

Tags: php, integer

Hay all, is there a PHP function which adds "+" to positive strings?

i.e

```
function(4) // returns +4
function(1.0) // returns +1.0
function(-1) // returns -1
function(0) // returns +0
```

Thanks

**EDIT:** wants to take and return strings.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get exactly this, since the 1.0 is just a plain 1 and there's no reason for PHP to remember its presence. You'd have to send it in as a string if you wanted it to work, but thanks to duck typing, the code of the function wouldn't have to be different.

Comment: What is this for? That decides whether the return value should be a string or not.

Comment: As pointed out, it doesn't take an integer. It actually takes a string. i.e. "0.00", "1.34".

Comment: @skilldrick - a bunch of STRINGS are sent. All negative values are already sent as negatives, like "-4.00". However all positive are sent without "+". I want to return positives with the "+".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use (s)printf with the following:

```
$number = sprintf('%+f', $number);
// "-0"  => +0.000000
// "1.2" => +1.200000
```

or

```
function formatPositive($number)
{
    return ($number > 0) ? "+$number" : $number;
    // "0"   => "0"
    // "-0"  => "-0"
    // "1.2" => "+1.2"
}
```

or

```
function formatPositive($number)
{
    switch(true) {
        case !is_numeric($number): // "Beer" => "NaN"
            $number = 'NaN'; 
            break;
        case $number == 0: // "-0" = "±0"
            $number "±0";
            break;
        case $number > 0: // "1.23" => "+1.23" 
            $number = "+$number";
            break;
        default:  // "-1.23" => "-1.23" 
            break;
    }
    return "$number";
}
```

Comment: Close, but it should be `>=` since he wants it to say `+0`. Also, shouldn't the second part of the ternary operator be `"$number"` so the function consistently returns a `String` vs. a string if positive and an integer if negative? (Oh, and +1 for using ternary form. Looks great)

Comment: sending "nothing" to that returns "+"

Comment: @Doug Zero is not a positive number, so it should not return + imho. If any it should have ±. Since PHP will automatically typecast as needed, I leave it up to the OP to decide on the return type.

Comment: @dotty: because you passed a string.

Comment: If $number is -0 (as returned by, e.g., _ceil(-.7)_ or _round(-.2))_, the first solution returns "+0.000000", the second returns "-0", and the third returns "±-0".

Comment: @GZipp pick the result you like most ;)

Comment: I don't like any of them. I was just pointing out some anomolies so that anyone else using your code would know what to expect.

Comment: @Gzipp i didnt notice the plusminusminus in the third one. fixed that. thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
$i = 3;
printf('%+d ', $i);

$i = -3;
printf('%+d ', $i);
```

prints `+3 -3` (and also works with [sprintf()](http://docs.php.net/sprintf) if needed)

Comment: You'd need a distinct line if the value is a float though.

Answer (score 3):

```
sprintf("%+d", 5);    # should give +5
sprintf("%+d", -5);   # should give -5
```

Quick reference: http://www.php.net/sprintf

Answer (score 0):

The PHP language reference for [sprintf](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) suggests "%+d" as a format specifier for positive signed integers.

Answer (score -2):

Home made function

```
function make_positive($int){
    if($int >= 0){
        return "+".$int;
    }else{
        return $int;
    }
}
```

Does PHP have its own?

**EDIT:** changed function name.

Comment: The only problem I see is that if its positive, your function returns a string, if its negative, it returns the integer. It probably should return a consistent type, right?

Comment: Also, a function named `is_foo` suggests it should return a `boolean` value.

Comment: make_positive is also a bad name, since that would imply it's returning the absolute value.  How about "add_sign"